# Java Final Variable Initialization in static block

Tags: java, variables, initialization, final

Assume the case:

```
public class Executor {

    public static class Properties {
        public final static String SOME_PROPERTY;

        static {                
            java.util.Properties properties = PropertiesReader.readProperties();

            SOME_PROPERTY = properties.getProperty("some.property");
        }
    }
}
```

Here all is fine and code compiles. But when we change it this way:

```
public class Executor {

    public static class Properties {
        public final static String SOME_PROPERTY;

        static {                
            java.util.Properties properties = PropertiesReader.readProperties();
            // The changes go here
            Properties.SOME_PROPERTY = properties.getProperty("some.property");
        }
    }
}
```

It's for some reason fails, with compilation error that

> **"final field could not be assigned"**

Could you please help by explaining the difference between first and second sample?